# DIY preamp configuration discovery implementation

Tags: pcb-design

I am building home automation hifi audio preamplifier, which consists of motherboard and arbitrary number of audio zones. Every zone is represented with pcb volume controller board (volume control IC with stereo audio input and audio output). Now, the end user will be able to upgrade/downgrade this preamp with adding/removing audio zones (minimal 1 zone - classic stereo, maximum 8 zones - true zone preamp). At power on, the motherboard with main microcontroller (Microchip PIC32MX795F512L) will have to figure out the configuration of preamp, i.e., figure out the number of zone pcbs, inserted into motherboard. What are the possible solutions for this task?

Comment: Each zone could have an wire that goes to the motherboard and tells it that the zone is present (e.g. by asserting that line high)

Comment: This will be closed due to too broad and open ended, so I'll be brief. 1: Passively pulled up line that is grounded when board installed. 2: Comm protocol that can detect no response. 3: Assume no zones exist until the ID themselves on some bus, like CAN.  Really though, this is your project.  There are many ways to do this.  Haven't you come up with *anything* so far?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Any advantages on the line being pulled to ground over it being pulled to Vcc?

Comment: I have, but I just wanted to ask other expert to get other ideas. I was thinking about some I2C memory with preprogrammed IDs and addresses and at bootup pic32 could read these addresses for values.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih A quiz program this isn't. If you have thought of some approaches, please try and respect other people's time on this site by starting with your existing strategy, and let people add/enhance/shoot down as they see fit.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I just wanted to research different approaches ...

Answer (score 2):

You are going old-school on this one.  Also, based on stuff that I'm probably reading into your question, I assume that you are wanting to make this into a commercial product.  So let me tell you how I would do this.  But before that, let me say that I am the lead EE on [this product line](http://www.qscq-sys.com/).  It does what you are talking about, but bumps it up by several orders of magnitude.

By the sound of it, you want to do your volume control in the analog domain.  This is just barely reasonable.  Modern digital pots are, in my opinion, crap.  They have high THD+N, and often worse than 20% matching between devices (different packages).  TI has some very nice programmable gain amps which are very nice, but also very expensive.

Additionally, doing the mixing in analog isn't a terrible thing, but it isn't good either.  If all you wanted to do was volume control and mixing then fine.  But a nice multi-zone "processor" usually needs more than just volume and mixing.  Throw in an EQ and you would be much better off going digital.  Once you go digital you can do things like ambient noise level compensation, ducking of the background music, or even auto-mixing of the audio based on motion sensor data.  The sky is the limit at that point.

This sounds expensive, but it isn't.  Not compared to what you are thinking of doing.  There are nice 8-channel ADC's and DAC's from Cirrus Logic and AKM.  Some of these are fairly inexpensive.  If you made your box support 8 or 16 channels it would cost less than having it configurable (with all the internal connectors, etc.) and it would be more reliable too.  Then add a nice DSP (there are many from Analog Devices that would work), or even an ARM Cortex-M4 or M8 instead of your PIC.

If your business model requires upgradability then you need to rework your model.  If you don't do something similar to what I outline, someone else will and they will have a solution that does as much as your 8-zone system for less than your base model.

Comment: Thank you for you guidelines, but I am far far away from commercial product, but this project is intended for private use and I cannot afford ARM development right now because I have development system for PIC32 family.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih  If all you have is a hammer...  :)